# Chrome shows "The site's security certificate is not trusted" error

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

From this morning I get this error whenever I access Google Docs and some websites. My system datetime is correct and I checked "Automatically from the Internet". My BIOS is OK. I cleared everything (cache, cookie, private data) in Chrome and restarted OS but nothing changes. **How to fix it?** Firefox works but Chrome has that problem.

> The site's security certificate is not trusted!
>
> You attempted to reach docs.google.com, but the server presented a certificate issued by an entity that is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This may mean that the server has generated its own security credentials, which Google Chrome cannot rely on for identity information, or an attacker may be trying to intercept your communications.
>
> You cannot proceed because the website operator has requested heightened security for this domain.

[image]

Comment: Seems Google don't trust themselves anymore..

Comment: Could my company block those sites? I think it could happen...

Comment: @Emerald214 - Ask your company.

Comment: This can happen if someone is re-routing you through a decrypting proxy. This is done in some corporates and dictatorship countries.

Comment: @Emerald214: It's not that they block it, it's that they insist on decrypting and re-encrypting it. Usually the stated reason is so that they can check for malware and the like. However, this requires you to explicitly configure your browser to trust them because, obviously, if a malicious entity did that, it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solutions:

- Check your system datetime again, set to manual to make sure that you have todays date (2012 at least). See: [Chrome bug #41886](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41886)
- Check if your [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file is not hacked.
- Check the Chrome plugins, if you don't see anything weird.
- Check different browsers if it works.
- And at last, run your Chrome browser from Terminal, it'll give you more details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new profile in Chrome

Comment: Can you please explain why you believe that would help?